# Return single taxonomy term outside the loop

Tags: taxonomy

I'm trying to list just the first taxonomy term outside the loop.

This is working fine but it lists all terms, and I just need the first - any suggestions?

```
    $taxonomy = 'taxonomy-name-here';
    $queried_term = get_query_var($taxonomy);

    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, 'slug='.$queried_term);
    if ($terms) {
      foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo ' ' . $term->name . ' ';
      }
    }
```

Edit:
clarification: the above seems to be returning all categories within the taxonomy, I'm only looking to get the taxonomy category of the current page.

Update:
I found a simple answer!:

```
$categories= wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'taxonomy-name');
echo $categories[0]->name;
```

Comment: ah, it all becomes clear now. you're on a single post page trying to get terms associated with that post, not a taxonomy term page, which is why `get_query_var($taxonomy);` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
$taxonomy = 'taxonomy-name-here';
$queried_term = get_query_var($taxonomy);
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', $queried_term, $taxonomy );
echo $term->name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't seem to return anything for me.

Comment: is this not a taxonomy term page?

Comment: No, this is going in the title tag, called only on the taxonomy page though.

Comment: I'm confused. yes it is a taxonomy page, or it isn't? taxonomy page meaning `site.com/your-taxonomy-name/the-taxonomy-term/`, that's the only context in which `get_query_var($taxonomy);` is going to contain a taxonomy term.

Comment: Sorry about that, yes it is a taxonomy page then. The code I posted above using get_terms() was working so that means your code should work too right?

Comment: it should. note that you'll get all terms back from a taxonomy if you just pass `slug=` to `get_terms` with no actual slug passed, so i'll guess that maybe you're not passing the correct taxonomy name so `$queried_term` is empty. echo everything and make sure it's what you expect it to be.

Comment: You're right $queried_term is empty, but $taxonomy returns the correct taxonomy.  I just checked and in my example above queried_term also returns empty, even though it returns the terms.

Comment: Is there any way to just limit get_terms to showing the first term?

Comment: it's returning all the terms because $queried_term is empty, which doesn't make sense if you're on a taxonomy term page. I'd say you have a plugin possibly interfering with the query. in your code you can just access the first element `$terms[0]->name`, but I don't see the point of that since it's not going to have any relation to the page you're currently on, other than it being the first term in that taxonomy. every taxonomy term page would give you that same first term.